# check development mode in Angular template

Tags: angular

how would one check the *development* mode in an Angular *template*?

It should be the equivalent of [`isDevMode()`](https://angular.io/api/core/isDevMode) and I would like e.g. to not display a `div` when in *production*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to your class

```
isDevMode: boolean = isDevMode();
```

And inside template

```
<span *ngIf='isDevMode'>Development Mode Enabled</span >
<span *ngIf='!isDevMode'>Development Mode Disabled</span >
```